# How to write a regular expression that contains the day and month?

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression for my .htacces file that matches the following:

```
gallery/a-day-like-today
gallery/a-day-like-today/
gallery/a-day-like-today/2-18
gallery/a-day-like-today/2-18/
```

Basically, the numbers (2-18) represents the month and the day. It could also contain 1 digit like 9-8 (september the 8th)

If there is a date, then both the month and the day are mandatory.

I started doing something but i'm stock. Any ideas how to achieve it?

```
^gallery/a-day-like-today(?:/(\d{1,12})-(\d{1,31})?)?$
```

My solution doesn't work because it picks days that are out of the range {1,31}

my htacces looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/a-day-like-today(?:/(\d{1,12})-(\d{1,31})?)?$ gallery/a_day_like_today.php?month=$1&day=$2 [L]
```

https://regex101.com/r/zkBQSJ/1

Comment: And a regex for number-number would not be good enough?

Comment: i tried: ^gallery/a-day-like-today(?:/(\d{1,12})-(\d{1,31})?)?$ but doesnt work when gallery/a-day-like-today/14-34

Comment: 14-34 is not a valid month-day... I'm confused. I'm also confused because you stated that month and day are both mandatory but two of your examples don't have month or day. Please edit your question and clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: I've clarified my question. If there is a date, then both the month and the day are mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `(\d{1,12})` I can tell that you try to do a range check for month 1...12. Your regex actually means a number 1 to 12 digits long. You can do a range check in regex, but it's a bit convoluted, meaning you might want to extract the numbers, and do the range check on the extracted numbers.

Here is a regex solution for your range check for month and day:

```js
const regex = /^gallery\/a-day-like-today(?:\/?|\/([1-9]|1[0-2])-([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/?)$/;
[
  'gallery/a-day-like-today',
  'gallery/a-day-like-today/',
  'gallery/a-day-like-today/2-18',
  'gallery/a-day-like-today/2-18/',
  'gallery/a-day-like-today/12-1/',
  'gallery/a-day-like-today/13-1/',
  'gallery/a-day-like-today/1-31/',
  'gallery/a-day-like-today/1-32/'
].forEach(str => {
  let m = str.match(regex);
  console.log(str, '==>', m);
});
```

Output:

```
gallery/a-day-like-today ==> [
  "gallery/a-day-like-today",
  undefined,
  undefined
]
gallery/a-day-like-today/ ==> [
  "gallery/a-day-like-today/",
  undefined,
  undefined
]
gallery/a-day-like-today/2-18 ==> [
  "gallery/a-day-like-today/2-18",
  "2",
  "18"
]
gallery/a-day-like-today/2-18/ ==> [
  "gallery/a-day-like-today/2-18/",
  "2",
  "18"
]
gallery/a-day-like-today/12-1/ ==> [
  "gallery/a-day-like-today/12-1/",
  "12",
  "1"
]
gallery/a-day-like-today/13-1/ ==> null
gallery/a-day-like-today/1-31/ ==> [
  "gallery/a-day-like-today/1-31/",
  "1",
  "31"
]
gallery/a-day-like-today/1-32/ ==> null
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^gallery\/a-day-like-today` -- literal text at beginning of string
- `(?:` -- non-capture group start

  - `\/?` -- optional slash
- `|` -- logical OR

  - `\/` -- literal slash
  - `(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])` -- capture group 1 for a single digit 1..9, or two digits 10...12
  - `-` -- literal dash
  - `(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` -- capture group 2 for a single digit 1..9, or two digits 10...29, or 30...31
  - `\/?` -- optional slash
  - `)` -- non-capture group end
- `$` -- end of string

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't check if the numbers make sense as a month day, but it's simple so maybe it will work for your case.

```
gallery/a-day-like-today/?(\d{1,}-\d{1,})?/?
```

BTW. Why not just check for `gallery/a-day-like-today` and not worry about what goes after?

Comment: Because i may need to pass a month and a day like so: gallery/a-day-like-today/3-21

Comment: i've tried playing with your solution so i can at least check if the numbers males sense with no success: ^gallery/a-day-like-today(?:/(\d{1,12})-(\d{1,31})?)?$

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches all your conditions plus I added more test cases

```
^gallery/a-day-like-today/{0,1}\d{0,2}-{0,1}\d{0,2}/{0,1}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/XqcYf6/1

---

If you want to return the month and day (when present), you can use the regex

```
^gallery/a-day-like-today/{0,1}(\d{0,2})-{0,1}(\d{0,2})/{0,1}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/8WYO0t/1

---

Test cases

```
gallery/a-day-like-today
gallery/a-day-like-today/
gallery/a-day-like-today/1-1
gallery/a-day-like-today/1-1/
gallery/a-day-like-today/1-31
gallery/a-day-like-today/1-31/
gallery/a-day-like-today/12-1
gallery/a-day-like-today/12-1/
gallery/a-day-like-today/12-31
gallery/a-day-like-today/12-31/
```

NOTE: This does not check whether the month-day pair are valid, only matches the pattern. For example, `/99-99/` would pass but not be a valid month-day pair. You'll have to tell me if this is OK or not.

Comment: is it possible to have it so i can pick the month and day : RewriteRule ^gallery/a-day-like-today(?:/(\d{1,12})-(\d{1,31})?)?$ gallery/a_day_like_today.php?month=$1&day=$2 [L]

Comment: @Marco I've added another regex for the return groups you requested. It's just adding `()`s around the section(s) you want returned. NOTE: It's not going to return anything if the month-day don't exist. You will need to account for that in your code.